# primeng p-menubar example not working

Tags: angular, primeng

I am getting the following error.  It is telling me that it can't bind the 'model' since it is not known by the 'p-menubar'.

I am very new with angular and primeng.  Can someone help me?

> Error: Template parse errors:
>       Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'p-menubar'.
>       1. If 'p-menubar' is an Angular component and it has 'model' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'p-menubar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
>       3. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
>                   ][model]="items">
>                       
>                       "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:23
>       'p-menubar' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'p-menubar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'p-menubar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("
>                   [ERROR ->]
>                       
>            "): ng:///AppModule/AppComponent.html@1:12
>         Evaluating http://localhost:3000/main.js
>         Loading main.js
>       Stack trace:
>       syntaxError@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1729:34
>       TemplateParser.prototype.parse@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:12967:19
>       JitCompiler.prototype._compileTemplate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27161:18
>       JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27080:56
>       JitCompiler.prototype._compileComponents@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27080:9
>       JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26967:13
>       then@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1718:92
>       JitCompiler.prototype._compileModuleAndComponents@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26966:16
>       JitCompiler.prototype.compileModuleAsync@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26895:32
>       PlatformRef_.prototype._bootstrapModuleWithZone@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4568:16
>       PlatformRef_.prototype.bootstrapModule@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4554:16
>       @http://localhost:3000/main.js:4:1
>       @http://localhost:3000/main.js:1:31
>       @http://localhost:3000/main.js:1:2
>       evaluate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2843:8
>       translateAndInstantiate/http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3608:21
>       dynamicExecute@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1166:18
>       doEvaluate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1113:13
>       ensureEvaluate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1022:13
>       RegisterLoader$1.prototype[Loader.resolveInstantiate]/http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:612:14
>       ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:392:17
>       Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:142:24
>       scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:844:52
>       ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:425:17
>       Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:28
>       drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:602:25
>       k/http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:31581
>       k/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:8:31451
>       s@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js:7:25990
>         localhost:3000:22:53

This is the app.component.ts code:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MenubarModule, MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            <p-menubar [model]="items">
                <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="Search">
                <button pButton label="Logout" icon="fa-sign-out"></button>
            </p-menubar>
  `
//   templateUrl: './app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent { 

    items: MenuItem[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {
                label: 'File',
                items: [{
                        label: 'New', 
                        icon: 'fa-plus',
                        items: [
                            {label: 'Project'},
                            {label: 'Other'},
                        ]
                    },
                    {label: 'Open'},
                    {label: 'Quit'}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                icon: 'fa-edit',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Undo', icon: 'fa-mail-forward'},
                    {label: 'Redo', icon: 'fa-mail-reply'}
                ]
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

This is the app.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  The "import { MenubarModule, MenuItem } from 'primeng/primeng';"  needs to be in the app.module.ts, not in the app.component.ts.